# Adding multiple constraints

Tags: sql-server, constraint

I am trying to add constraints and I think i have an error in the code as its saying i cant add mutlple constrints. What is best way to add mutlple constraints

I am using MSQL Server 2008 r2

```
CREATE TABLE [erp].[table](
    [SysRevID] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [SysRowID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL DEFAULT (CONVERT([uniqueidentifier],CONVERT([binary](10),newid(),(0))+CONVERT([binary](6),getutcdate(),(0)),(0))),
    [Company] [nvarchar] (8) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    --THE ABOVE ARE DEFAULT FIELDS.  LEAVE THEM ALONE.  ADD FIELDS BELOW
    [AffilationNum] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),   
    [VendorNum] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [CreationClass]   [nvarchar] (10),  
    FOREIGN KEY ( VendorNum ) REFERENCES Vendor (VendorNum),
    PRIMARY KEY (AffilationNum),
CONSTRAINT [idxEvAffiliation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Company] ASC,
    [AffilationNum] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

go

 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idxAffilationInterestedParty] ON [erp].[EvAffiliation]
 (
 [Company] ASC,
 [VendorNum] ASC
 )


GO

ALTER TABLE [erp].[EvAffiliation] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = DISABLE)
GO
```

**Edit**
 I am not sure how to create an additional index i dont want the second one to be on primary key its just an additional non clusted index i want for the second one.

This is the errror i am getting i am trying to create one pimary index and one non clustered index

> Msg 8110, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Cannot add multiple PRIMARY KEY constraints to table 'erp.EvAffiliation'.

Comment: Which of the 3 statements throws the error? What error **exactly** do you get? (and is the table named `[EvAffiliation]` or `[table]`?)

Comment: Oh, it's that you are trying to add 2 `PRIMARY KEY` constraints. This is not allowed.

Comment: You can have a `PRIMARY KEY` and a `UNIQUE` constraint. Or 2  (or more actually) `UNIQUE` constraints if you want to and no PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: @ypercube please see edit below code i not wanting to i need a second index just not on the primary key

Comment: @ypercube can you please provde an example of the constraint so i can add a second index thanks and il mark as answer

Comment: You have two PRIMARY KEYs. See the lines `PRIMARY KEY (AffilationNum),` and `CONSTRAINT [idxEvAffiliation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`. Remove one if you do not want two.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the erp.table, you are defining primary keys multiple times.

Try the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE [erp].[table](
    [SysRevID] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [SysRowID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL DEFAULT (CONVERT([uniqueidentifier],CONVERT([binary](10),newid(),(0))+CONVERT([binary](6),getutcdate(),(0)),(0))),
    [Company] [nvarchar] (8) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    --THE ABOVE ARE DEFAULT FIELDS.  LEAVE THEM ALONE.  ADD FIELDS BELOW
    [AffilationNum] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [VendorNum] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [CreationClass]   [nvarchar] (10),
    FOREIGN KEY ( VendorNum ) REFERENCES Vendor (VendorNum),
CONSTRAINT [idxEvAffiliation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [Company] ASC,
    [AffilationNum] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Refer to [Primary Key Constraints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191236%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Composite Primary Keys](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx).